# React and Redux error - first time with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm new in the React world. I got a course to training React and Redux.

Even though, I walk through the author course and copy the code from the screen I get an error:

Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).

The error happens as soon as I run a npm start, open the browser and got this error.

I have uploaded my code to github: https://github.com/tarcisiocorte/reactredux.git

I will appreciate some help.

Comment: Seems like a component is returning null from render, can you post a full log of the error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with [this line](https://github.com/tarcisiocorte/reactredux/blob/master/src/index.js#L5). Provider is not a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Description) of react-redux, so you should be importing it as `import { Provider } from 'react-redux';`.

Good luck with your React Redux journey :-)